# TabHost: переключение между вкладками

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Создала TabHost с двумя вкладками следующим образом:

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // инициализация была выполнена в getTabHost
    // метод setup вызывать не нужно

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 1");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, OneActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 2");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Как можно переключиться между вкладками в программе? Необходимо, находясь в первой вкладке, открыть вторую...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec(VKGroupListUserGroupsActivity.GROUP_TYPE_MY);
    spec.setContent( R.id.tab1 );   
    tabComponent = new TabComponent( getApplicationContext() );
    spec.setIndicator( tabComponent.currentTab( Res.getString(R.string.my_group) ) );
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    .............//Определение табов

    TabListener = new TabChangedListener();
    TabListener.setContext(this);
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener( TabListener );

    TabListener.checkTabChanged( choiceTag  );

   .............
```

Собственно далее создал класс

```
public class TabChangedListener implements OnTabChangeListener

public void checkTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
    //Реакция по нажатию

}
```

Comment: @vor4un, не смогла понять что вы написали.... Возможно ваш вариант хорош :)

Answer (score 2):

tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

Comment: @Gorets, это я могу сделать из главного активити, в котором определяю tabhost. но когда у меня открыта вкладка (соответственно другое активити) я не могу так обратиться..

Comment: TabHost tbh = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

tbh.setCurrentTab(2);

пишешь в экшене на нужной активити

Comment: @Gorets, так не выходит, т.к. я не могу увидеть R.id.tabhost в активити, которая во вкладке, потому что это видно только во вкладке, которая является главной(в которой определены сами вкладки)

Answer (score 0):

Сделала еще один класс, в который из главного активити записала сам tabhost:

```
private TabHost tabHost; 
public TabHost getTab() {
      return tabHost;
     }
 public void setTab(TabHost var) {
      tabHost = var;
     }
```

Так вот при создании главного активити в onCreate записываю туда TabHost и при экшене в нужной мне вкладке могу легко и просто работать с вкладками(public TabHost getTab()...)